# Minor bug in the recent activity code for the election tracker

Tags: bug, status-completed

With some elections starting up, I have noticed an on and off bug with the recent activity portion of nominated candidates.

http://elections.stackexchange.com/ - pick any race (I've seen it on Apple most recently)

If you show none in the "Nomination|Profile|None" control at the top right of the page, it's easier to see this duplication of recent activity, but not necessary for the page to report the same action twice.

It seems to come and go on different candidates, but happens enough that it seems to be a more than 10% of the time error.

[image: duplicate entries in recent activity]

Is this something wrong on the browser end that I can fix to reduce this error or might it be a bug in the code that generates the last few edits? (or some quirk in the internal storage of some types of edits)

Comment: Looking into it.

Comment: -1 because you didn't use freehand circles.. :o( Well, I haven't really downvoted, but I would have liked to see this nice display of artistic taste.. ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API harness being used on the site is making a second call to the timeline API route with a smaller page size than the first call, causing some results to be returned more than once. I think this is fixed in my local copy as part of an overhaul of the client-side code, but I'll verify.

These changes should be completed sometime later tonight and will hopefully go out shortly thereafter.

Comment: Can you check to see if the code fix is live and working as intended? The question was tagged status-completed 9 hours ago, but I am still seeing duplicate entries - see my answer below...

Comment: No, the change hasn't been deployed yet. The [meta-tag:status-completed] was in anticipation of the redeploy, I suppose, which is still pending because I didn't get home until late this evening.

Comment: Also, to be more clear, "shortly thereafter" likely means tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this :-)